# LSTM 'recurrent_dropout' with 'relu' yields NaNs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, numerical-stability

Any non-zero `recurrent_dropout` yields NaN losses and weights; latter are either 0 or NaN. Happens for stacked, shallow, `stateful`, `return_sequences` = any, with & w/o `Bidirectional()`, `activation='relu'`, `loss='binary_crossentropy'`. NaNs occur within a few batches.

Any fixes? Help's appreciated.

---

**TROUBLESHOOTING ATTEMPTED**:

- `recurrent_dropout=0.2,0.1,0.01,1e-6`
- `kernel_constraint=maxnorm(0.5,axis=0)`
- `recurrent_constraint=maxnorm(0.5,axis=0)`
- `clipnorm=50`  (empirically determined), Nadam optimizer
- `activation='tanh'` - no NaNs, weights stable, tested for up to 10 batches
- `lr=2e-6,2e-5` - no NaNs, weights stable, tested for up to 10 batches
- `lr=5e-5` - no NaNs, weights stable, for 3 batches - NaNs on batch 4
- `batch_shape=(32,48,16)` - large loss for 2 batches, NaNs on batch 3

*NOTE*: `batch_shape=(32,672,16)`, 17 calls to `train_on_batch` per batch

---

**ENVIRONMENT**:

- Keras 2.2.4 (TensorFlow backend), Python 3.7, Spyder 3.3.7 via Anaconda
- GTX 1070 6GB, i7-7700HQ, 12GB RAM, Win-10.0.17134 x64
- CuDNN 10+, latest Nvidia drives

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**:

Model divergence is spontaneous, occurring at different train updates *even with fixed seeds* - Numpy, Random, and TensorFlow random seeds. Furthermore, when first diverging, LSTM layer weights are all normal - only going to NaN later.

Below are, in order: (1) inputs to `LSTM`; (2) `LSTM` outputs; (3) `Dense(1,'sigmoid')` outputs -- the three are consecutive, with `Dropout(0.5)` between each. Preceding (1) are `Conv1D` layers. Right: LSTM weights. "BEFORE" = 1 train update before; "AFTER = 1 train update after

*BEFORE divergence*:
[image]

*AT divergence*:
[image]

```
## LSTM outputs, flattened, stats
(mean,std)        = (inf,nan)
(min,max)         = (0.00e+00,inf)
(abs_min,abs_max) = (0.00e+00,inf)
```

*AFTER divergence*:
[image]

```
## Recurrent Gates Weights:
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 0.,  0., -0., ..., -0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -0., -0., ..., -0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 0.,  0., -0., ..., -0.,  0., -0.],
       [ 0.,  0., -0., ..., -0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
## Dense Sigmoid Outputs:
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

---

**MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**:

```
from keras.layers import Input,Dense,LSTM,Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers  import Nadam 
from keras.constraints import MaxNorm as maxnorm
import numpy as np
```

```
ipt = Input(batch_shape=(32,672,16))
x = LSTM(512, activation='relu', return_sequences=False,
              recurrent_dropout=0.3,
              kernel_constraint   =maxnorm(0.5, axis=0),
              recurrent_constraint=maxnorm(0.5, axis=0))(ipt)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(ipt,out)
optimizer = Nadam(lr=4e-4, clipnorm=1)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

```
for train_update,_ in enumerate(range(100)):
    x = np.random.randn(32,672,16)
    y = np.array([1]*5 + [0]*27)
    np.random.shuffle(y)
    loss = model.train_on_batch(x,y)
    print(train_update+1,loss,np.sum(y))
```

**Observations**: the following *speed up divergence*:

- *Higher* `units` (LSTM)
- *Higher* # of layers (LSTM)
- *Higher* `lr` **<<** no divergence when `<=1e-4`, tested up to 400 trains
- *Less* `'1'` labels **<<** no divergence with `y` below, even with `lr=1e-3`; tested up to 400 trains

`y = np.random.randint(0,2,32) # makes more '1' labels`

---

**UPDATE**: not fixed in TF2; reproducible also using `from tensorflow.keras` imports.

Comment: You really have 1350 timesteps? That will make learning very unstable.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro No stability issues with 10,000+ timesteps as long as `recurrent_dropout=0` (though model struggles to learn, weights don't misbehave)

Comment: That's precisely what unstable learning means, you move one thing and the model breaks and the loss goes to infinity or nan.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Tried with 48 timesteps, no change. Model converges for a large variety of configurations, only `recurrent_dropout` is problematic

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MLguy No, but it's on my to-investigate list - will get around to it

Comment: To note a caveat on myself in response to @MatiasValdenegro, 1350 timesteps with LSTMs is a pretty bad idea - not so much per instability as per inability to learn long-term dependencies. Can see this explicitly by [visualizing gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017288/how-to-visualize-rnn-lstm-gradients-in-keras-tensorflow/59017289#59017289)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I eat my words on instability - but an explanation was due. Apparently we both missed what should be obvious.

Comment: @MLguy Figured it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Studying LSTM formulae deeper and digging into the source code, everything's come crystal clear.

**Verdict**: `recurrent_dropout` has nothing to do with it; a thing's being looped where none expect it.

---

**Actual culprit**: the `activation` argument, now `'relu'`, is applied on the *recurrent transformations* - contrary to virtually every tutorial showing it as the harmless `'tanh'`.

I.e., `activation` is *not* only for the hidden-to-output transform -  [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2028); it operates directly on computing *both recurrent states*, cell and hidden:

```py
c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(h_tm1_c, self.recurrent_kernel_c))
h = o * self.activation(c)
```

[image]

---

**Solution(s)**:

- Apply `BatchNormalization` to LSTM's inputs, *especially* if previous layer's outputs are unbounded (ReLU, ELU, etc)

  - If previous layer's activations are tightly bounded (e.g. tanh, sigmoid), apply BN *before* activations (use `activation=None`, then BN, then `Activation` layer)
- Use `activation='selu'`; more stable, but can still diverge
- Use lower `lr`
- Apply gradient clipping
- Use fewer timesteps

---

**More answers**, to some remaining questions:

- *Why was `recurrent_dropout` suspected?* Unmeticulous testing setup; only now did I focus on forcing divergence without it. It did however, sometimes accelerate divergence - which may be explained by by it zeroing the non-relu contributions that'd otherwise offset multiplicative reinforcement.
- *Why do nonzero mean inputs accelerate divergence?* Additive symmetry; nonzero-mean distributions are asymmetric, with one sign dominating - facilitating large pre-activations, hence large ReLUs.
- *Why can training be stable for hundreds of iterations with a low lr?* Extreme activations induce large gradients via large error; with a low lr, this means weights adjust to prevent such activations - whereas a high lr jumps too far too quickly.
- *Why do stacked LSTMs diverge faster?* In addition to feeding ReLUs to itself, LSTM feeds the next LSTM, which then feeds itself the ReLU'd ReLU's --> fireworks.

---

**UPDATE 1/22/2020**: `recurrent_dropout` may in fact be a contributing factor, as it utilizes *inverted dropout*, upscaling hidden transformations during training, easing divergent behavior over many timesteps. Git Issue on this [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35724)