# Very Low Accuracy With LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I don't have any idea about low accuracy in my configuration (always 0.1508).
Data shape : (1476,1000,1)

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_X = scaler.fit_transform(train_Data)

....

 myModel = Sequential()

 myModel.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(myData.shape[1:]),activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
 myModel.add(Dropout(0.2))
 myModel.add(BatchNormalization())

 myModel.add(LSTM(128,activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
 myModel.add(Dropout(0.2))
 myModel.add(BatchNormalization())

 myModel.add(LSTM(64,activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
 myModel.add(Dropout(0.2))
 myModel.add(BatchNormalization())

 myModel.add(LSTM(32,activation='relu'))
 myModel.add(Dropout(0.2))
 myModel.add(BatchNormalization())

 myModel.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
 myModel.add(Dropout(0.2))

 myModel.add(Dense(8,activation='softmax'))
 #myModel.add(Dropout(0.2))

 opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001,decay=1e-6)
 ls  = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
```

Also sometimes following warnings:

```
W1014 21:02:57.125363  6600 ag_logging.py:146] Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x00000188C58C3E18> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: 
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x00000188C58C3E18> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause:
```

Answer (score 4):

Two main culprits are: `Dropout` layers, data preprocessing. In detail & others:

- `Dropout` on stacked LSTMs is known to yield poor performance, as it introduces too much noise for stable time-dependency feature extraction. **Fix**: use `recurrent_dropout`
- If you are working with signal data, or otherwise data with (1) outliers; (2) phase information; (3) frequency information - `MinMaxScaler` will corrupt the latter two plus amplitude information per (1). **Fix**: use `StandardScaler`, or `QuantileTransformer`
- Consider using `Nadam` optimizer over `SGD`; it proved vastly dominant in my LSTM applications, and is generally more hyperparameter-robust than `SGD`
- Consider using `CuDNNLSTM`; it can run **10x faster**
- Ensure your data's shaped properly for LSTM: `(batch_size, timesteps, features)` - or equivalently, `(samples, timesteps, channels)`

*Note of warning*: if you do use `recurrent_dropout`, use `activation='tanh'`, as `'relu'` is [unstable](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13221).

---

**UPDATE**: True culprit: insufficient data. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433022/keras-over-fitting-conv2d?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-58455292)

Comment: Thanks for that note of warning at the end... Wish I would have seen that in the docs.

Comment: @Andy It's quite a problem, yet no response on Github - maybe I'll open an issue on TF instead. I intend on debugging it myself eventually - can sub to the thread to be notified.

Comment: I've been seeing you all over the TF Github, thanks so much for your valuable diagnostic work on these issues

Comment: @Andy Surprised and glad to hear that you have - you're welcome.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thanks for reply. I tried your methods they were useful but there wasn't any obvious changes in the results. Then I decided to reshape my data and try convolutional layers. Results were the same as LSTM but training is much more faster than LSTM. Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433022/keras-over-fitting-conv2d

Comment: @Codie What is the application? What's the input and output data? (stocks, weather, signals, etc)

Comment: Which of above suggestions have you tried (all)? `MinMaxScaler` _will_ be a major problem for signals. Are you able to share a batch or a sample of your data (via e.g. [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com))?

Comment: @Codie This is your _entire dataset_? Then that's the problem: it's not nearly enough for deep learning, especially for data beasts likes of stacked LSTMs. You're better off with a SupportVectorMachine, or at most LSTM + Dense + Dropout

Comment: @Codie I can quickly test a minimal DL model if you'd like, just share your validation data

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon this is whole the data that I have. For training, validation and test. I use 0.1 of data for validation through defining validation_split parameter.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon you can find my results here, they are the same as LSTM: [Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433022/keras-over-fitting-conv2d)

Comment: @Codie How do you use `Dense(16)` softmax if your label shape is `(8,)`? Output dense units should match # of classes

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I use dense(8).

Comment: @Codie Updated.

Comment: @Andy Finally [figured it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516678/lstm-recurrent-dropout-with-relu-yields-nans/59656753#59656753). Frankly I'm surprised noone else did, even on Keras Github; I at least had an excuse of being relatively new to RNNs at the time.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you were spot on about both `dropout` and `StandardScaler` vs `MinMax` :-D