# Keras: Over fitting Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a convolutional based model. I trained two different structures as following. As you can see for single layer there isn't any obvious change along number of epochs. Bi-layer Conv2D presents improving in accuracy and losses for train dataset, but validation characteristics are going to be a tragedy.
According to the fact that I can't increase my data-set what should I do to improve validation characteristics?
I've examined regularizer L1 & L2 but they didn't affect my model.
 [image: Figures]
[image: SpatialDropout2D]

Comment: Make sure if you're using dropout on your Conv2D layers it's `SpatialDropout2D`

Comment: There are several techniques to deal with overfitting. Regularization is the first one, if it is not affecting your results you are either not using it properly or the factor is too small - at some point you should always see _some_ difference. Dropout is another common technique, and batch normalization may help a bit. Data augmentation also helps, if you can do that.

Comment: @jdehesa I can't use data augmentation. Of course I can see slightly changes but not positive ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a variety of models known to work well on small datasets, but as I suspected, and as is my ultimate verdict - **it is a lost cause**.

You don't have nearly enough data to train a good DL model, or even an ML model like SVM - as matter's exacerbated by having *eight* separate classes; your dataset would stand some chance with an SVM for binary classification, but none for 8-class. As a last resort, you can try XGBoost, but I wouldn't bet on it.

**What can you do?** Get more data. There's no way around it. I don't have an exact number, but for 8-class classification, I'd say you need anywhere from 50-200x your current data to get reasonable results. Mind also that your validation performance is bound to be much worse on a bigger validation set, accounted for in this number.

---

For readers, OP shared his dataset with me; shapes are: `X = (1152, 1024, 1), y = (1152, 8)`

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You can use adaptive learning rate (exponential decay or step dependent may work for you) Furthermore, you can try extreme high learning rates when your model goes into local minimum.

**2)** If you are training with images, you can flip, rotate or other stuff to increase your dataset size and maybe some other augmentation techniques might work for your case.

**3)** Try to change the model like deeper, shallower, wider, narrower.

**4)** If you are doing a classification model, please ensure that you are not using *sigmoid* as your activation function in the end unless you are doing binary classification.

**5)** Always check your dataset's situation before training session.

- Your train-test split may not be suitable for your case.
- There might be extreme noises in your data.
- Some amount of your data might be corrupted.

**Note:** I will update them whenever a new idea comes to my mind. Furthermore, I didn't want to repeat the comments and other answers, both of them are having valuable information for your case.

Comment: I'd actually be fine with you adding my comment about spatial dropout to your list, it does bear repeating

Comment: @Andy thanks for reply. I'm trying to check spatial dropout. I'll report it.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for replys. Results of adding two SpatialDropout2D to the model have been added to the first post. As you can see there is only a shift in losses (the results in 1000th epoch are same as results in previous model without SpatialDropout2D in earlier epochs) . According to try and errors and what Physicing mentioned in the post, I think its because of small dataset and nature of data that I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

The validation becomes a tragedy because model is  overfitting on the training data you can try if any of this works,

1)Batch normalisation would be a good option to go with.
2)Try reducing batch size.

Comment: I already tried batch normalization and it didn't present positive improvements. @ArunJose_Intel