# Keras Loss "NaN"; Likely Exploding Gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm running an LSTM model to classify astrophysics time series data. I am attempting to classify each time series as either a black hole (1) or not a block hole (0). When I run my RNN, the loss is not decreasing (actually increasing then going to NaN). I cannot figure out how solve this problem. Here is the link to my Jupyter Notebook (which contains more information on the problem).

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NJBEIdoeToqdcYooGEtrVfaELtLXwNjZ?usp=sharing#scrollTo=d_HDprISPjZT

Let me know if you know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably [ReLU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59656753/10133797); try `activation="tanh"`.

Here's additional text for no reason because stack overflow thinks one can never answer a question this briefly.

Comment: I switched all the ReLUs to tanh and now the gradient is no longer exploding, but it's not decreasing. It's simply staying stable. Any suggestion on how to fix that?

Comment: @user23472342 That's a separate question, feel free to open it.

Comment: I'm aware but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user23472342 Try asking on [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DS](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), and provide relevant information about the problem _in your question_.